# The difference between "&(epage->incoming[0]) = spage;" and "&(epage->incoming[p2]) = spage;"

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-arrays, lvalue

The last line of this particular code block produces the error "lvalue required as left operand of assignment". The confusion lies in why the last line throws this error while the second to last line doesn't.

```
      int p2 = 0;
      spage = find(in.startpage);
      spage->noutgoing++;
      spage->outgoing = (struct webpage *)realloc((spage->outgoing),((spage->noutgoing)*sizeof(struct webpage)));

      epage = find(in.endpage);
      epage->nincoming++;
      epage->incoming = (struct webpage *)realloc((epage->incoming),((epage->nincoming)*sizeof(struct webpage)));


      position = ((epage->nincoming));

      &(epage->incoming[0]) = spage;
      &(epage->incoming[p2]) = spage;
```

where `spage`, `epage` are structs defined below:

```
struct webpage {
   char name;               /* name of page */
   struct webpage *outgoing;    //array of pointers pointing to outgoing webpages
   struct webpage *incoming ;   //array of pointers pointing to incoming webpages
   int noutgoing;
   int nincoming;
};
```

and the function `find` returns a pointer to a `struct webpage`.

Problem was resolved by changing the structs `outgoing` and `incoming` to double pointers and changing the last line to `(epage->incoming[p2]) = spage;`.

Still don't know why the error happened though...

Comment: Both of those should give the same error: you cannot assign to the rvalue. Example: http://codepad.org/vmmr9cA2

Comment: Which compiler? Which version?

Comment: Compiler version is gcc 4.2.1?

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
struct S {
    int * p;
};

int main() {
    struct S * s;
    int n;
    &(s->p[42]) = 0;
    &(s->p[n]) = 0;
}
```

compiled with GCC 4.5.1, produces:

```
n.c:9:16: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
n.c:10:15: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

In other words, both cases produce the lvalue needed error. Can you try this exact code with your compiler?

Comment: The above code threw the same errors as above on my compiler (gcc 4.2.1 ) ie:

`s.c: In function ‘main’:`
`s.c:8: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`
`s.c:9: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`

Comment: @gillian So please post a complete, compilable example (by editing your question) of code which produces the error (or lack of it) that you say you are getting.